# number locales can't be identified in LWUIT components

Tags: string, java-me, locale, lwuit

Here is my label component:

```
Label totalPrice = new Label();
totalPrice.setText(shoppingList.getTotal() + "00 " + "T");
```

There's a number part "getTotal()" which generates dynamically in run-time, and other constant strings "00 T".
The question is what should I do to make this work and translates fine with locale resource? (I'm facing this issue in Table components too)

I've tried to look for "Formatter" or anything like that, but I found nothing.

thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no formatters in CLDC/MIDP. Its really unclear what the expected result is?

Generally you need to format things manually in j2me.

Comment: hey Shai, is'nt it a good idea to add formatter to lwuit/code-name-one?

Comment: I opened an issue about this in the issue tracker. We will add something like that to Codename One when we can.